# Can't debug Golang in vscode apple m1

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

Starting debugging, I get:

```
API server listening at: 127.0.0.1:23350
```

And debugger hangs, I cannot step into, step over, step out. Only can stop and restart.

go version is

```
go version go1.16.4 darwin/arm64
```

launch.json is

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch file",
        "type": "go",
        "request": "launch",
        "mode": "debug",
        "program": "${file}"
    }
    ],
}
```

Comment: You have the `amd64` version of `go` installed. You need `darwin/arm64`. Read the following bug ticket: https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/2246

Comment: I updated the go sdk. And get another problem. Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: This is not an issue with VS Code or Delve. Use version 1.6.1 for a fix.

---

This problem was a bug in LLVM. Checkout the [bug report](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=50169). There is a bug in the GoLand bug tracker that is a bit more interesting to read though: [related GoLand bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-11011).

Solution:

Use version `1.6.1` of Delve.

See: https://github.com/go-delve/delve/releases/tag/v1.6.1

From the Changelog:

```
Correctly read G address on linux/arm64
```

That's the fix for the issue.